# About synchronized in java.io.PrintStream

Tags: java, io

Does anybody know why the member call println of PrintStream is synchronized?

For example: `public synchronized void println (String str)`

But why there is no synchronized for `public void println (char[] chars)`?

Comment: Which version of Java ?

Comment: In Java 6, 7, and 8 the `println` methods are not synchronized. However, they have a synchronized block in the method's implementation - in all of those `println` methods. So, to which Java version do you refer?

Comment: In Java 8 neither method is synchronized, but they do synchronize internally (both of them)

Comment: Both of the methods are synchronized internally, not to mixup printing statement if called up from different source.

Comment: From where did you find this     public synchronized void println (String str) ... which jave version... to which URL you have referred

Comment: Hello, I am a android developer. I think it should be Java 6.

Comment: And my problem is on Android 4.4.

Comment: @user3236879 You didn't mention any problem.

Comment: On google developer doc, you can see my question is there:

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/PrintStream.html#println%28java.lang.String%29

Answer (score 1):

I have checked the [given link](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/PrintStream.html#println%28java.lang.String%29)

As per the method signature it says `println(String)` is synchronized and `println(char[])` is not. However, when you read the description of `println(char[])` it says it prints the string representation of the given `char[]` i.e. it implicitly converts the given `char[]` to `String` and calls the `println(String)` method.

So even though `println(char[])` is not synchronized it achieves the synchronization implicitly by calling `println(String)`.